# Index of coincidence String java

Tags: java, string, hashmap

```
public static double indexOfCoincidence(Map<Character, Integer> m) {
    double indexOfCoincidence=0;
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> charmap : m.entrySet()) {
        double coincidence = charmap.getValue().doubleValue()/totalCharacters;
        indexOfCoincidence= indexOfCoincidence+ Math.pow(coincidence, 2);
    }

    return indexOfCoincidence;
}
```

I am trying to create a method that calculates the index of coincidence of a text .The index of coincidence should be defined by the following formula :

[image: \left(\frac{numberOfA}{totalcharacter} \right)^2 + \left(\frac{numberOfB}{totalcharacter} \right)^2+ ... + \left(\frac{numberOfZ}{totalcharacter} \right)^2]

I am passing the method a map with all characters and their number of occurrence.I am getting a result 0.011307961449881282. But when I check the index online I get answer 0.045...... I am not sure where I am wrong

Comment: What is `totalCharacters`?

Comment: @azurefrog The total number of characters in the string

Comment: Do you have an example input?  Try testing with something small like "a", "aa", and "cat", and see if they produce the desired results

Comment: Where did you define `totalCharacters`?

Comment: Sorry, overlooked your code. If you are trying to do that for Shannong algorithm, tere are plenty of codes on Internet though.

Comment: public static int totalCharacters=0;

Comment: Are you sure about your formula? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_coincidence

Comment: @RC. Well isn't it the same ?